# How can I see the invocation stack of functions together with their arguments after Interrupt?

Tags: debugging, interruption

I know that by pressing **Alt+comma**, I can interrupt a running task. This brings me to an interactive environment as if there would have been a command `Interrupt[]` (probably after) the current line of execution in my code. I can inspect or even change global variables in this interactive environment.

But how do I address the local variables (i.e. those with the strange names like neu$1234567 created by the first argument of every Block or Module)? How do I know which one belongs to which stage?

1. How can I see which line in my code will be executed after I execute
   Return[]?
2. Is there something which lets my notebook window focus onto that
   line?
3. How can I see the sequence of functions and their respective
   arguments which were active at the moment of interruption
   (invocation Stack and parameters on the respective invocations)?
4. Is there something which lets me focus to the line up or down one level of invocation?
5. How can I inspect the local variables (i.e. declared in the first
   element of Block or Module) on the various invocation levels of
   those functions?